# Weird number appears when printing object

Tags: r, igraph

When creating an igraph object I get these strange numbers appearing in between `IGRAPH` and the codes that describe the network properties (`e367cdc`, in this object). I've also used the example graphs and they have similar strange codes. The graph appears to operate OK so not a problem - I'm just curious, that's all.

```
library(igraph)

g1 <- graph( edges=c(1,2, 2,3, 3, 1), n=3, directed=F ) 

g1

IGRAPH e367cdc U--- 3 3 -- + edges from e367cdc:[1] 1--2 2--3 1--3
```

I'm using igraph version 1.2.1.

Comment: I've updated my post to be reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the info is as follows:

`IGRAPH 69d704e` = Graph number randomly generated.

`UN--` = Undirected Named

`15554` = Number of nodes

`109746` = Number of edges

`attr: name (v/c), disease (v/n), hub (v/n), ptype (v/c), comp (v/n) + edges from 69d704e (vertex names)` = attractors, this is detailed information enclosed on your network.

Comment: Thanks BioCrazy, must be some randomly generated number then. I've never noticed it before.

Comment: Yes, it is randomly generated. It is not really important as long as you can see the rest of the info. Good luck!